# Automatic repeat of one task until another is finished (TAP)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

I have two operations - long running OperationA and much quicker OperationB. I was running them in parallel using TAP and returning results as they both finish :

```
var taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>OperationA());
var taskB = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>OperationB());
var tasks = new Task[] { taskA, taskB };
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
// processing taskA.Result, taskB.Result
```

No magic here. Now what I want to do is repeat OperationB when it's finished indefinitely in case OperationA is still running. So whole procedure finish point will occur when OperationA is finished and last pass of OperationB is finished. I'm looking for some sort of effective pattern for doing that will not involve polling for OperationA's Status in while loop if that's possible. Looking toward improving WaitAllOneByOne pattern proposed in this [Pluralsight course](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=intro-async-parallel-dotnet4) or something similar.

Comment: is polling OperationA's status such a problem? You only need to do it once for every iteration of OperationB, and it's only a bool check so it's really cheap

Comment: Not really, both tasks can be changed easily if I wanted. The problem is this model described here is simplified version of what I'm trying to implement, and adding much dependencies and pollings may complicate the solution more it is expected to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took your approach as basis and adapted a bit :

```
var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = source.Token;
var taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => OperationA()
    );
var taskAFinished = taskA.ContinueWith(antecedent =>
    {
        source.Cancel();
        return antecedent.Result;
    });

var taskB = Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => OperationB(token), token
    );
var taskBFinished = taskB.ContinueWith(antecedent =>
    {
        switch (antecedent.Status)
        {
            case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
            case TaskStatus.Canceled:
                try
                {
                   return ant.Result;
                }
                catch (AggregateException ae)
                {
                   // Operation was canceled before start if OperationA is short
                   return null;
                }
            case TaskStatus.Faulted:
                return null;
        }
        return null;
    });
```

Made two continuations that returns results for respective operations so I could make wait for them both to be finished (tried to do that only with second one and it didn't work).

```
var tasks = new Task[] { taskAFinished, taskBFinished };
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

First one is just passing antecedent's task Result further, second takes aggregate results available at this point in OperationB (both RanToCompletion and Canceled statuses are considered correct end of process). OperationB now looks like this :

```
public static List<Result> OperationB(CancellationToken token)
{
    var resultsList = new List<Result>();
    while (true)
    {               
        foreach (var op in operations)
        {
            resultsList.Add(op.GetResult();
        }
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return resultsList;
        }
    }
}
```

Changes logic a bit - all loops inside OperationB now are considered as single task, but this is easier than keep them atomic and write some sort of coordination primitive that will gather results from each run. In case I don't really care which loop produced which results this seems to be a decent solution. May improve to more flexible implementation later if needed (what I was actually looking for is to chain multiple operations recursively - OperationB itself may have smaller repeating OperationC's inside with same behavior, OperationC - multiple OperationD's that are running when C is active etc.).
*edit*
Added exception handling in taskBFinished for case when OperationA is quick and cancellation is issued before OperationB is even started.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// Get cancellation support.
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = source.Token;

// Start off A and set continuation to cancel B when finished.
bool taskAFinished = false;
var taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => OperationA());
Task contA = taskA.ContinueWith(ant => source.Cancel());

// Set off B and in the method perform your loop. Cancellation with be thrown when 
// A has completed.
var taskB = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => OperationB(token), token);
Task contB = taskB.ContinueWith(ant => 
    {
        switch (task.Status)
        {
            // Handle any exceptions to prevent UnobservedTaskException.             
            case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion: 
                // Do stuff.
                break;
            case TaskStatus.Canceled:
                // You know TaskA is finished.
                break;
            case TaskStatus.Faulted:
                // Something bad.
                break;
        }
    });
```

then in the `OperationB` method you can perform your loop and include a cancellation upon TaskA's compleation...

```
private void OperationB(CancellationToken token)
{
    foreach (var v in object)
    {
        ...
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // This must be handeled. AggregateException.
    }
}
```

**Note, instead of complicating with a cancellation, you can just set a bool from with in the continuation of TaskA and check for this in TaskB' loop - this will avoid any faffing about with cancellations.**

I hope this helps

Comment: Interesting approach, will try it. Thanks for effort.